# Open interval disassembled into open countable many disjoint cubes and a set with lesbegue measure 0

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure

How can i show that every open not empty interval $I\subset\mathbb R^n $ can be disassembled into a countable number of open disjoint cubes $W_k$ and a set $N$ with Lebesgue Measure $0$ in the form: $$I=N  \cup\bigcup\limits_{k=0} W_k $$

Also show that: $\mu(I)=\sum^\infty_{k=0} \mu(W_k)$

Comment: Welcome. By "interval", do you mean an open rectangle, i.e. a product of open $1$-dimensional intervals?

Comment: Did you mean finitely many cubes, or infinitely many cubes? Your post contradicts

Comment: Hi Fshrike, i tried to translate this question from a german book. 
Yes as you wrote they definied interval as a product of open 1-dimensional intervals and there should be countable many cubes, not finitely many.

Comment: In which case it is a theorem that any open set in $\Bbb R^n$ can be written as *the almost disjoint union of closed rectangles* (consider dyadic partitions). If you know that almost disjoint means "intersection is null" and that the countable union of null sets is again null, then you are done

Comment: See page $14$ of [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf), it holds for any open set not just product intervals